# Bind TreeView to XMLDocuent of unknown depth

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

I'm trying to bind a XMLDocument that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <topic id="INDEX">
    <title>Index</title>
    <url>...</url>
    <topic id="Result">
      <title>Result</title>
    ...
```

where the depth of the nesting is unknown. How do i bind this to a TreeView in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HierarchicalDataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx). That's what's commonly used in conjunction with a TreeView.

I haven't used them with XML data before (are you loading your XML into an XDocument?), but it appears that using an [XMLDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx) together with HierarchicalDataTemplates is the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605062/treeview-bound-to-xmldataprovider-shows-data-in-editor-but-empty-when-run).

Answer (score 0):

I have actualy cracked it... The clue were to use

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <Binding XPath="child::node()[@id]" />
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
```

that filters out any node without an id atribute, and a trigger like

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Text" Value="{Binding XPath=title}" />
        </DataTrigger>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
```

where tb is a simple textbox.